# retrieve text value from an element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have an HTML element with a value in it:

```
<span id="mySpan">23</span>
```

How can I retrieve this value (23) and use it? I've tried something like:

```
var num = $("#mySpan").text();
```

Does not seem to work... Will I be able to use it as a number to add other numbers to it?

Comment: works fine on my side `var num = $("#mySpan").text();
console.log(+num);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). You should also make sure that the selector is returning the DOM elements you expect it to.

```
var num = parseInt($("#myspan").text(), 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the DOM is loaded before your code runs:

```
$(function() {
    var num = +$("#mySpan").text();
    alert( num );
});
```